# Kotlin Activity cannot be null with Websocket

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragments, websocket

When a websocket connection is made I want to show an alert message with Alerter(UI) library that connection is made succesfull. But it crashes every time when I want to show the message.
It gives me the error: "Activity cannot be null" Probably because I call the function from another Class.

This is the code.

```
class MainInstall : Fragment() {

    
         ...


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        btnConnect.setOnClickListener {
            val checkUri = hostnameInput.text.toString()

                checkConnection(checkUri)

        }
        

    }



    private fun checkConnection(url:String){

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("wss://$url/temp/true")
            .build()
        val wsClien = client.newWebSocket(request, EchoWebSocketListener())

    }
    

    fun alertBericht(){
        Alerter.create(activity)
            .setTitle("Alert Title")
            .setText("Alert text succesfull")
            .show()
    }

}




class EchoWebSocketListener : WebSocketListener() {
    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
        output("Connected")
        MainInstall().alertBericht()
    }
  ...
}
```

How can I update my UI when the Class is not the Main?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the listener in `MainInstall`:

```
class MainInstall : Fragment() {
    private val listener = object : WebSocketListener() {
        override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
            output("Connected")
            alertBericht()
        }  
        ...
    }
}
```

Then update `checkConnection()`:

```
val wsClien = client.newWebSocket(request, listener)
```

Comment: Thank you @veritas1 it worked like a charm, nice way to output action ;)